# PHP: name parameters when passing them to a method?

Tags: php, function, methods, naming-conventions, parameter-passing

Some languages allow us to name parameters when passing them to methods, e.g.:

```
private static function hello(a, long, list = 0, of = 0, parameters = 0)
{
    ...
}

self::hello(a=1, long=2, list=3, of=4);
```

It certainly simplifies reading code in some cases. Is there a similar functionality in php?

The most simple construction that I could imagine is:

```
self::hello(/*a*/ 1, /*long*/ 2, /*list*/ 3, /*of*/ 4);
```

[offtopic]Love Obj C... It **requires** to name parameters:`[self helloA:1 long:2 list:3 of:4];`[/offtopic]

Comment: As does java, there is tons to read about on google ;)

Comment: Pasted some code below. If you end up testing it and find issues, update me please as I'll be using this too in the future. It's fun :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP **does not provide such functionality** but it can be faked to a large degree of realism. I just wrote this thing. Not 100% tested but if used correctly, it will work.

**Example** of how you use it:

```
call_user_func_args(function($a1, $a2, array $a3 = null, $a4 = null){
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}, array(
    'a1'    => 1,
    'a3'    => null,
    'a2'    => 2,
));
// Output
array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => null
```

It uses `\` in front of classes as it's namespaced code intended for **use with PHP 5.3 or later**. Remove the `\` to try to use it in 5.2, but no guarantees.

Here is the code:

```
/**
* Calls a function with named arguments.
* Just written and quite tested. If you find bugs, please provide feedback and I'll update the code.
* In a sane usage scenario, it will work. If you try your best, you might break it :)
* If true, $ValidateInput tries to warn you of issues with your Arguments, bad types, nulls where they should not be.
* 
* @copyright Claudrian
* @param callable $Callable
* @param array $Arguments
* @param bool $ValidateInput
* @return mixed
*/
function call_user_func_args($Callable, array $Arguments, $ValidateInput = false){
    // Make sure the $Callable is callable
    if(!is_callable($Callable)){
        trigger_error('$Callable is not a callable.', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    // No arguments, no game
    if(empty($Arguments)){
        return call_user_func($Callable);
    }

    // Validate the input $Arguments
    array_change_key_case($Arguments, CASE_LOWER);
    foreach($Arguments as $ArgumentName => $ArgumentValue){
        if(empty($ArgumentName) or is_numeric($ArgumentName)){
            trigger_error('$Arguments cannot have numeric offsets.', E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        if(!preg_match('~^[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*$~', $ArgumentName)){
            trigger_error('$Arguments contains illegal character offsets.', E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Get access to the function
    try {
        $Reflector = new \ReflectionFunction($Callable);
    } catch(\Exception $Exception){
        trigger_error($Exception->getMessage(), E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    // If function has not arguments, just call it but it's stupid
    $RequiredParameterCount = $Reflector->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
    $ParameterCount = $Reflector->getNumberOfParameters();
    if(!$ParameterCount){
        return call_user_func($Callable);
    }

    // Prepare the $Parameters
    $Parameters = array();
    $PresetParameters = array();
    foreach($Reflector->getParameters() as $Parameter){
        $LowerName = strtolower($Name = $Parameter->getName());
        $Argument = ($Available = array_key_exists($Name, $Arguments)) ? $Arguments[$Name] : null;
        $Default = ($IsDefault = $Parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) ? $Parameter->getDefaultValue() : null;
        $Parameters[$LowerName] = array(
            'Name'              => $Name,
            'Offset'            => $Parameter->getPosition(),
            'Optional'          => $Parameter->isOptional(),
            'Nullable'          => $Parameter->allowsNull(),
            'Reference'         => $Parameter->isPassedByReference(),
            'Array'             => $Parameter->isArray(),
            'Defaultable'       => $IsDefault,
            'Default'           => $Default,
            'Available'         => $Available,
            'Provided'          => $Available ? $Argument : $Default,
        );
    }

    // Pop pointless nulls (from the last to the first)
    end($Parameters);
    while($Parameter = current($Parameters)){
        if(!$Parameter['Nullable'] or !$Parameter['Optional'] or !is_null($Parameter['Provided'])){
            break;
        }
        array_pop($Parameters); // Pop trailing null optional nullable arguments
        prev($Parameters); // Move one back
    }

    // Prepare the final $Arguments
    $Arguments = array();
    foreach($Parameters as $Name => $Parameter){
        if($ValidateInput){
            if(is_null($Parameter['Provided']) and !$Parameter['Nullable']){
                trigger_error("Argument '{$Name}' does not accept NULL.", E_USER_NOTICE);
            }
            if($Parameter['Array'] and !is_array($Parameter['Provided'])){
                if(!$Parameter['Nullable'] and is_null($Parameter['Provided'])){
                    trigger_error("Argument '{$Name}' should be an array.", E_USER_NOTICE);
                }
            }
            if(!$Parameter['Available'] and !$Parameter['Optional'] and !$Parameter['Defaultable']){
                trigger_error("Argument '{$Name}' is not optional and not provided.", E_USER_NOTICE);
            }
        }
        // Stoe this in the final $Arguments array
        $Arguments[] = $Parameter['Provided'];
    }
    // Invoke the actual function
    return $Reflector->invokeArgs($Arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$a=1;
$long=2;
$list=3;
$of=4;
self::hello($a, $long, $list, $of);
```

Other way, would be to use setters to set the values in object before You call hello.
Though in Your example it's a private method...

Your reference here should be http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Yes, I've read that page before posting, and [this one](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=20544), too. I still think that `hello(/*a*/ 1, ...` is more simple... The most simple?

Comment: Simpler or not, when we are talking about PHP, the answer to Your original question is simply: no. There is no such functionality in PHP now. And what happens if You change the name of params in Your function definition ? Will You then update all calls to it too? You document the function at it's definition, not at function calls.